# Sharing a database handle

Tags: ruby, database-connection, dbi, sharing

I need to share a database handle among a few Ruby scripts. I am using the DBI gem to connect to the database. Consider the following example

```
#a.rb
class A
  require 'dbi'

  def connect
    if a database handle is already open return it
    else create a new one and return it
  end
end

#b.rb
class B
  require 'a'
  a = A.new
  dbh = a.connect
  #some database queries here
end

#c.rb
class C
  require 'a'
  a = A.new
  dbh = a.connect #Here the database handle created by class B should be returned 
end
```

I understand that class instance variables are the way to go to achieve the said goal. Can someone please provide some insight on this?

Does DBI have something similar to Log4r

```
class A
  require 'log4r'
  Log4r::Logger.new('SO') #create a new instance here
end

class B
  require 'a'
  Log4r::Logger['SO'] # get the existing instance here
end
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses a [Singleton](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) to manage a hash of DBI handles.  It will create a new handle for a given set of connect options (the args one would pass to DBI.connect) the first time a connect is requested with those options. Subsequent requests with the same options will get the already open handle.

```
# there_can_be_only_one_dbh.rb

require 'dbi'
require 'singleton'

class ThereCanBeOnlyOneDBH
  include Singleton

  DEFAULT_CONNECT_OPTIONS = ['dsn','user','pw']

  def connect( *options )
    options = DEFAULT_CONNECT_OPTIONS unless options and !options.empty?
    @handles ||= {}
    @handles[options.join('|')] ||= DBI.connect( *options )
  end
end

# b.rb
require 'there_can_be_only_one_dbh'

class B
  def initialize( *dbi_connect_options )
    @dbh = ThereCanBeOnlyOneDBH.instance.connect( *dbi_connect_options )
  end

  # methods which issue queries using @dbh
end

# c.rb
require 'there_can_be_only_one_dbh'

class C
  def initialize( *dbi_connect_options )
    @dbh = ThereCanBeOnlyOneDBH.instance.connect( *dbi_connect_options )
  end

  # other methods which issue queries using @dbh
end
```